# AS3 - How do I code a particular frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

So its like I want a code just for frame 2. Is there any other way other than just going to frame 2 and typing in the Actions Panel? For example I am using a class called supportForce and I want a part of the code to apply only for frame 2. This might be stupid but just in order to get a doubt cleared I asked this question, forgive me if I am wasting your time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, simply write your code from the parent scope of **supportForce** inside a statement such as this one:

`if(supportForce.currentFrame == 2) { //DO MAGIC ON FRAME 2! }`